# legend on each point with pylab.plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, legend

I would like to have  each exact value as a legend above each point representing that value on my graph. Any idea of how  I can do it? Thanks
    enter code here

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`annotate` method](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) of matplotlib. If you provide some example code, I'll show you how you could use it. Otherwise, the documentation and the examples of matplotlib are quite nice.

Comment: this is my code. diffTemps is a table.
pylab.plot(range(1,32),diffTemps)
pylab.title('Day by Day Ranges in Temperature in Boston in July 2012')
pylab.xlabel('Days')
pylab.ylabel('Temperature Ranges')

Comment: You should post a self-contained example with sample data in your original question. That would make it easy for people to modify it.